# How to fix my code based off of feedback from mocha error

Tags: javascript, debugging, mocha.js

My assignment is to write getElementsByClassName from scratch (please don't provide help for this aspect). Mocha is going to throw lots of errors back in my face until I get it correct.

Is there any way to determine where the error is in my code based on the the error message below? I feel like Mocha is pointing back at my source, getElementsByClassName.js, but I'm not sure exactly how the numbers correspond to my lines of code.

Thanks for your insight!

[image]

Comment: My guess is that getElementByClassName:10 is the column and getElementByClassName:31 is the line, isn't?

Comment: The first number is the line, the second the column. The first file is where the error was thrown, the rest is how it bubbled up (only matters if it is meant to be caught somewhere).

Comment: Can either of you explain the column part? I knew my code had lines, but not columns.

Comment: If a line of code is `if (1) {`, then `if` is at column 1, `(` is at column 4, etc. It is, literally, the count of characters in the line so far.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @PaulRoub. I would've assumed it started at 0 and included whitespace without your example.

Comment: @jgillich: Want to officially answer the question so I can give you credit?

Comment: Starts at 1, *does* include whitespace. `if (` - `(` is the 4th character in. Space is a character.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on my counting...sheesh...I need to take a break! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first line under `Type Error` shows where the current error is at. I expect a function to be defined at line 10, column 31, but it is not.